# how to call aspx.vb method using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

how to call vb.net method from ajax I send array as parameter in the ajax and it's not working
this is the ajax and javascript  code

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   

        <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#Button1").click(function () {
                    var Years = document.getElementById("Options").querySelectorAll(".selected");
                   


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "NewScenarioProfilePage.aspx/CalculateSum",
                        data: "{'yearvalue ':'" + Years  +  "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: OnSuccess,
                        failure: function (response) {
                     ' this alert didn't show 
                            alert(response.d);
                        }

                    });

                });
```

and this is the vb method
P.s this yearvalue maybe be an array if it's more than 2 values or it will be an integer variable if it's one value

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
 
 Public Shared Function CalculateSum(ByVal yearvalue as Integer) As String
        MsgBox("calculate sum")

        Dim Result As Integer = yearvalue 
        Return Result.ToString()
    End Function
```

and the msgbox doesn't fire.
I don't know what the problem is.
this is the error in the inspect when I click on the button

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST https://localhost:44351/NewScenarioProfilePage.aspx/CalculateSum 401
send    @   jquery.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   NewScenarioProfilePage:477
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
r.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: MsgBox is not to be used on webpages. I use XMLhttpRequest to trigger ashx handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You got a 401 status code as a response. So, probably you missing authentication mechanism.

Comment: i  set the Set Anonymous Authentication to Application Pool Identity. from here     IIS ->
Authentication --> Set Anonymous Authentication to Application Pool Identity. and still have the same errors !

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I think you need to remove that server side msgbox - it will BIG TIME mess this up, since ajax calls are async.

Try this example:

Lets drop in two text boxes, a button, and take the value from first text box, run it through the function (say times 2 for fun).

So we have this for the server code:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function CalculateSum(ByVal yearvalue As Integer) As String

    Debug.Print("cal sum run!!")

    Dim Result As Integer = yearvalue * 2

    Return Result.ToString()

End Function
```

And for client side? lets not just have the js code kind of "sitting" there - lets call a routine, and do the post.

So lets drop in a standrd asp.net button - but NOTE how we ONLY call client side code with that button (onClientClick). and we use return false so the button does not post-back.

```
    <div>
        Enter year:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test Ajax call"
            OnClientClick="mytest();return false"/>
        <br />
        Result ajax from server: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <script>
        function mytest() {

            myyear = $('#TextBox1').val()

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AjaxTestFun.aspx/CalculateSum",
                data: JSON.stringify({ yearvalue: myyear }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rData) {
                    // put results send back into TextBox2
                    $('#TextBox2').val("Result from server = " + rData.d)
                },
                failure: function (rData) {
                    alert("error " + rData.d);
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

So, the output looks now like this:

[image]

So, I used a debug.print. Use that or console log, since when you start using ajax calls - then a server side msgbox can often hurt you.

And if the current web page works fine, then tossing in a web method also will work (it it NOT an authentication issue).

I also used JSON.stringify. It "assumes" the first value is text, and the 2nd value can be a variable like I used such as mymyear, or you could use '12335' under quotes.

So that stringify REALLY helps world poverty and suffering by you not have to try and concatenate  up a bunch of variables, and a HUGE mess of single or double quotes.

Comment: thanks i tried it but still have this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery.min.js:2 POST https://localhost:44351/AjaxTestFun.aspx/CalculateSum 404
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
mytest @ NewScenarioProfilePage:478
onclick @ NewScenarioProfilePage:233`

Comment: Does any standard button say for a test you drop onto the page work? And is this web method on the web page, or separate? Also, when the page first loads, hit ctrl-F5 to force a re-load of the browser cache - I blown out a afternoon due to cached js code. I assume that jQuery is working?

Comment: Well, you have to change AjaxTestfun to the name of your page? Maybe your page name is different? - maybe you created a new one, but it does require the name of the web page you created.

Comment: yes, i change it but it's still not working!

Comment: Does dropping a standard asp.net button and doing say a debug.print in the code behind work? Have you tried a break-point in the web method routine? Does that work? Create a new blank web test page. does the sample I have posted here work?